# Set correct timezone in PHP Date function

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, timestamp-with-timezone

I have written my first wordpress plugin that looks at a file on the server and returns the timestamp.  My problem is that the server's timestamp is 8AM but the returned value is 13:00.  How can I adjust the time stamp in PHP to match the real time?  Here is the code I have used:

```
function wp_file_last_updated( $atts ){
$a = shortcode_atts ( array(
    'url' => 'No File Specified'
    ), $atts );

$filename = $a['url'];
if (file_exists($filename)) {
return "$filename was last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename));
}
}
add_shortcode('filedate', 'wp_file_last_updated');

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should set the timezone in wordpress settings

OR

Set the default timezone in the beginning of your php file with the following php function
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: The wordpress timezone didn't help, but adding in the PHP function did the trick!  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set("set supported time zone");
$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Supported time zones are listed at http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Thanks!  That fixed it..I appreciate you taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

I am on amazon Lightsail and changing timezone from WordPress admin area doesn't work for me. 
If you are using Lightsail, you will need to change the timezone from a server level.

```
// list all the timezones
timedatectl list-timezones

// change to the your choice of timezone     
sudo timedatectl set-timezone America/Vancouver

// display the current selected timezone
timedatectl
```

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=754347